# How can build my project with conan without copying sources

Tags: cmake, conan

I have C/C++ project configuring with cmake and building with `conan create`, using `conanfile.py`.

I do not need to export my sources in packages that I will upload. I need only put the generated library in the package. So, I do not need to use `export_sources` in `conanfile.py`. Also, `export()` method (or its equivalent `export` attribute), I do not know why, but takes too much time to copy my source files from its original folder into conan cache folders, although there is only one 1KB small .txt file.

First, I want to describe what I mean with each type of folder:

**Original folder:** The path `conanfile.py` as well as `CMakeLists.txt` and my sources(.cpp), in src directory. Also note that I execute `conan create` within this path.

**Conan cache folders:** Conan creates its own temporary folders to work: build, source, export, etc. In `source()`, `build()`, etc. methods of `conanfile.py`, attributes like `source_folder` of `ConanFile` already refers to these cache folders, and not to **original folder**. Also note that conan copies `conanfile.py` also in these cache folders and the path of `__file__` also gives these cache folders.

So, in `build()` method, when I do "`self.run('cmake` " I need to refer to the **original folder** but `ConanFile` does not have it, as far as I know. It seemed to strange to me because I do not believe that my case is so strange. I would expect that Conan already has a solution for this.

So, is this a bad practice or is there a solution of Conan that I do not know?

Note that `no_copy_source` attribute does not make a difference, because it is about only no copying between Conan cache folders.

If anyway I need to copy my sources from the original path into the Conan cache folders, why `export`, or `copy` takes too much time even for a single 1kb file of same machine? (With too much time I mean, for copying that small file, it got stuck 1 minute. What does it wait for?)

Either case, how should I do?

**conanfile.py**

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools
import shutil, os, inspect

class MyConan(ConanFile):
    name = "MyLib"
    version = "0.0.1"
    generators = "cmake"
    no_copy_source = True
    exports = "CMakeLists.txt" # Takes too much time to copy it

    def source(self):
        current_dir = os.getcwd() # This already points to cache folders
        

    def source(self):
        # self.source_folder is pointing to cache folders. I have already lost path of original folder 


    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        #self.run('cmake %s --preset="my-preset"') HOW TO REFER TO my original source folder? Or HOW TO copy my sources to Conan cache folders without taking too much time
        #cmake.build()
```

**command:**

```
cd /path/of/conanfile/and/sources
conan create . 0.0.1/whatever/hotfix
```

Comment: It should definitely not take long to copy the CMakeLists.txt, it should be instantaneous. I'd recommend submit a reproducible example to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues (including a small project or link to a git repo with instructions how to reproduce)

Comment: Also, it seems you are using quite legacy things there, like ``generators = "cmake"``, which has been deprecated time ago in Conan 1.X in favour or ``CMakeDeps`` and ``CMakeToolchain``, and has been removed in Conan 2.0. I'd suggest updating.

Comment: @drodri Still it takes too much time. I could not find the reason. It is complicated to reproduce maybe. I have the following setup: Host: Windows 11 + WSL2, dockerd: running on WSL2, docker container: source files mounted from windows, conan: runs in docker container.  Could it be related with this setup? But still why? I can copy, move files immediately in shell, or other apps or python scripts running in container. Conan can not! I am frustrated with this.

Comment: Yes, it totally seems related to the setup, normal Conan copies relatively large sets of files in much less time, so there is something there that is not working as expected, could be some weird intersection of the host-guess docker setup, the Python versions, etc. the only way that this could be investigated is sharing some reproducible setup, maybe some docker images with the Conan team in their Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build in the Conan cache via `conan create` will always do a copy somehow of the sources. The goal is to make sure the package creation is fully reproducible from source, and also guaranteeing a clean build.

If you don't want to **upload** a copy of the sources, you can use the `scm` approach, which captures the coordinates (url, commit), instead of doing a copy. Still, it will do a new clone/checkout in the Conan cache. The goal is to make things fully

If you only want to package the final binaries, that you build locally, you can use the `conan export-pkg` functionality (see [this link](https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/creating_packages/other_types_of_packages/package_prebuilt_binaries.html)). But this won't allow building the package later, for example to automatically add a new configuration, and will not allow the `--build=missing`, for example.